# Double for each to linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, c#-4.0

Im very new to using linq and having trouble to rewrite the following double foreach to linq query

```
foreach(var country in europe)
{
    foreach(var europianCountry in unitedKingdom)
    {
        if (country.language == europianCountry.language)
        {
            countries.add (country.language);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like `var countries = europe.Where(e => unitedKingdom.Select(uk => uk.language).Contains(e.language)).ToList();`

Comment: Why the -1 on this question...?

Comment: @object88: Well let's start with **this isn't a question**. There's no question asked here. The question, such as it is, shows no effort, we don't know what the OP has tried, we don't know where they are having difficulty, there's no work shown whatsoever.

Comment: That's true.  I suppose I inferred a little into what a question might be, which isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by translating the inner loop:

```
foreach(var country in europe)
{ 
    countries.AddRange ( 
        from europeanCountry in unitedKingdom 
        where country.language = europeanCountry.language 
        select country.language);
}
```

Then translate the outer loop:

```
    countries.AddRange ( 
        from country in europe
        from europeanCountry in unitedKingdom 
        where country.language = europeanCountry.language 
        select country.language )
```

Then realize that you are doing a filtered cross product, which is logically a join:

```
countries.AddRange (
    from country in europe
    join europeanCountry in unitedKingdom 
    on country.language equals europeanCountry.language
    select country.language
)
```

Now, I note that there may be more efficient and sensible ways to structure this query. "Are there better ways to structure this query?" is not the question you asked; "how do I translate loops into queries?" is the question you implied -- I note that no question was ever actually asked.

You do it **one loop at a time**. Get each loop translated correctly, then move on to the next.